# Quick suggestions don't work while inside snippet placeholder

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

Summary:

As you can see in the gif file below, suggestions show up as we type `sysout` when not inside any snippet placeholder, otherwise, they don't show up.

Already tried:

I looked on GitHub issues and filed a GitHub issue.

[image: Snippet Not Working]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft support was on it quickly: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/72582

"Quick suggestions and snippet placeholder often collide and by default quick suggestions are disabled when snippet mode is active. This setting controls that behaviour: `editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions`" was their reply.

So basically, `editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions` need to be set to false in `settings.json`