# How to allow completion suggestions to appear while inside a snippet in Monaco Editor?

Tags: monaco-editor

I am using the `monaco-editor` library to implement a web editor for a custom programming language.

I have implemented a `CompletionItemProvider` to provide custom completion suggestions.

It works great in general. However, while a snippet is being executed (for example, while the user is typing in the "$1" placeholder of the snippet), completion suggestions are not shown, and the user has to press Ctrl+Space for them to appear.

This [related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55855330/quick-suggestions-dont-work-while-inside-snippet-placeholder)  describes the problem and its solution for the Visual Studio Code editor itself, but how can completion suggestions be allowed during snippet completion, when using the `monaco-editor` library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When creating the editor instance, provide the `suggest` editor option, with `snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions` set to `false`, as shown below:

```
const editor = monaco.editor.create(element, {
   value: value,
   language: myLanguageId,
   theme: myThemeId,
   suggest: {
      snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions: false
   }
});
```